# How to disable android wear palm close?

Tags: android

I'm trying to disable an app closing when a user puts their palm over the watch face.

Is there an easy way to disable this? I've been using keepScreenOn as a property but it doesn't seem to handle this event.

Thanks!

Comment: Dude, do not do this. Android wear has this fundamentally built into its system as a "turn off screen" feature (which ultimately saves battery). And it is even built into the tutorial for Android wear setup. At least explain why you would need to override this behavior before someone suggests a solution.

Comment: I'm integrating an android wear screen into some physical hardware, but I need it to not close the app when this happens. I have a button on another device that closes it so I don't have the battery problem.

Comment: Well, sounds good enough reason have you taken a look at the AOSP source for Android Wear? https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/android-4.4w_r1 Unfortunately, Im not sure how to use this repo...

Comment: Never looked at it before...I was thinking if I could capture that event and maybe force re-open??